# Unable to pass query string parameters to sign up form

Tags: iron-router, user-accounts

I'm trying to debug why any query string parameters aren't pre-filling the fields. My aim is to pass an email in the query string, so that the user doesn't need to type it again when registering.

http://my.splendido.site/sign-up?email=giorgio@example.com

I'm using a template "signUp" with {{> atForm state='signUp'}}

User-accounts Iron router package version 1.12.3 https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/iron-routing

I've added a few debug statements to at_input.js template helper, but it doesn't seem to run at all. How can I debug why query string doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry it was a bug introduced with [this commit](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/commit/28a2b4b4e5fffb19ccc68f84378bb2387d12d0ac) and now fixed with [this one](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/iron-routing/commit/f5e0d578adc69ac5e76ce90327ed59ac93a61815).
I'm going to release a new version soon so that with `useraccounts:iron-routing@1.12.4` everything should be fine!

I'm sorry for having caused this problem.